# Monofor droid VS 2012 navigate to another page using button

Tags: c#, android, visual-studio-2012, xamarin.android

Here is the problem right now.
create a simple axml file

Main.axml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:orientation="vertical"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="fill_parent">

      <Button
    android:id="@+id/MyButton"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/Hello" />
    </LinearLayout>
```

and here is the register.axml file

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
      <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       android:orientation="vertical"
       android:layout_width="fill_parent"
       android:layout_height="fill_parent"> 

       <EditText
        android:id="@+id/registerID"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="70dp"
        android:hint="ID" />
   </LinearLayout>
```

i searched a lot at this forum but what i found the code was in java.
and im using c# in VS2012 to do so.
and i searched a lot internet and failed to find for it.

can anyone give some idea ?

Comment: You mean to open a new screen, `register.axml`, by clicking the button on the first screen?

Comment: @aaron . ya . that's what i want..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just like with Java Android, Xamarin.Android uses both `Activities` and `Fragments` for displaying content and navigation.

The most simple sample would be that you create two `Activities`. One Main `Activity`, with you first layout, and a second one with your `register.axml` layout.

The button in the Main `Activity`, has a `Click` event, which you can do whatever you want, when it is clicked, i.e. start the second `Activity`. This can be done with an `Intent`, which Android uses i.e. for navigation:

```
var button = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.MyButton);
button.Click += (s, e) => {
    var intent = new Intent(this, typeof(SecondActivity));
    StartActivity(intent);
};
```

I recommend you to [read the documentation Xamarin has](http://docs.xamarin.com/guides/android/), which goes through these basic things.

Comment: Thanks ! Worked perfect. but just to tell you that.
c# cannot assign var button, it's has to be Button button. Thanks for your teaching , really thanks !

Comment: Of course you can do `var button`. Since C# 3.0 it has been possible to use implicit typing using `var`.

Comment: so for my own understanding. why i not able to do with var ?

Comment: I can only guess without any information on what the exact error was.